# How do I remove my YouTube feed activity content from my user profile page?

Tags: youtube, privacy

I've been successful in removing what's visible on my channel page (e.g. `https://www.youtube.com/channel/abc123`), by adjusting my privacy settings.

However, some activity of mine from a few years ago is still publicly visible under my user profile page (e.g. `https://www.youtube.com/user/username`). The two different pages seem to have some independence from one another.

Can anyone please help me out here?